# Using ta.change on a lower time frame

Tags: pine-script

I'm creating an indicator for a daily chart, and I want to know the price change of the last 2 hours. I tried using the following code, but it's giving incorrect values. Should I be doing something different?

`request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', ta.change(close, 2))`

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
close1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', close)
close2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', close[1])

priceChange = close1 - close2
priceChangeInPercent = ((close1 - close2) / close2) * 100
```

I mainly use ta.change() as a bool condition, never used it to calculate the difference.

Answer (score 0):

max change ratıo for 2 period
math.max(ta.change(close), 2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).